# Creating full screen activity in android for all android versions starting from gingerbread

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I need to create an android app containing an webview in my activity. The webview activity has to shown in full screen without showing the title bar. So I have given like this in my manifest:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

also in my mainactivity.class. I have given like this before the setcontentview:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Also in my main activity I have given like this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Now I want this app to be developed for all versions of android starting from 2.3 Gingerbread. Now the problem comes. When I run this on 2.3.6 Gingerbread, the app works fine in full screen. Where as when I try to run it on version 4.3 Jelly Bean, the app force closes. What is the problem behind this? How to make this app support on all versions of android?

I have searched many times in stackoverflow, but did't find a solution to my problem. That's why I ask it as a question. Any help from anyone is easily appreciated...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
else{
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

Hope this helps!